# Vim execute bash commands/make in the same window

Tags: linux, bash, vim

When i try to run some commands like `:make` or `:!ls` , it shows the output in an altogether different screen/view and the file i am editing is not visible during this process.
Is there anyway i can still see my file and edit, while the command that i executed can probably run in a window at the bottom, probably the quick fix window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using vim 8 or neovim, maybe you would like to try :

http://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim ,

Nice replacement to vim-dispatch with much better user experience.

[image]

- Easy to use, just start your background command by :AsyncRun (just
  like old "!" cmd).
- Command is done in the background, no need to wait for the entire process to finish.
- Output are displayed in the quickfix window, errors are matched with errorformat.
- You can explore the error output immediately or keep working in vim while executing.
- Ring the bell or play a sound to notify you job finished while you're focusing on editing.
- Provide corresponding user experience in vim, neovim, gvim and macvim.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin for asynchronous build (make).

or if you simply want shell command result in a quickfix window you coud use in ex-mode:

```
:cexpr system('ls -alh') | copen
```

even better, add this to you .vimrc

```
command -nargs=+ Run :cexpr system('<args>') | copen
```

and run in ex-mode:

```
:Run ls -alh
```

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is totally normal. CLI Vim doesn't come with a terminal emulator and will *never* do. GUI Vim comes with a dumb terminal emulator, though, and I think that's what you "remember long back".

You need a plugin for running commands in a separate Vim window. [ConqueTerm](https://code.google.com/p/conque/) is the only name I can remember at the moment but I think there are one or two others.

Comment: Can you run vim inside ConqueTerm?

Comment: Haha. I don't even want to know.

Comment: @romainl I do not want it to run in a separate shell. In a vim file, if i press : , it is being displayed in the last line in the monitor. Now, when i execute the command, let the command run in bash, but is there any way that the output be shown either in the last line again, or in a quickfix window?

Comment: When you do `:make` and there are errors, those errors are *always* listed in the quickfix window. If you want the output of some arbitrary command to be displayed in the quickfix window you must read through `:h quickfix.txt` which tells you how to format the output of your commands for use in the qf. But I suspect a serious case of XY problem, here: displaying the output of some commands in the qf window is a mean, what *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Like romainl said, this is the normal behavior. Vim does not store the output, acting like a pager it is only shown while the external command is executed. You could capture the command output in a scratch Vim buffer (`:r !ls`), use a plugin like the mentioned *Conque*, or split a shell window outside of Vim with the help of a terminal multiplexer like *screen* or *tmux*.

Answer (score 0):

Would splitting the **vim** windows work for you?

- **:split** - splits window horizontally
- **:vsplit** - splits window vertically

Then you can use of the windows just for editing the file and the second one for executing via **:make**.

Comment: No, i remember long back, in another system that the output used to come automatically in a small horizontal window at the bottom. I just dont know why its currently going to a different shell when this is executed...

Comment: @MIkhail: You could use Vim within a terminal multiplexer such as `tmux` to get similar functionality.

Comment: @DanielAndersson I live and sleep in tmux :). But, :make in vim helps me in jumping to line numbers with errors, which wont be there if i run make in another window.

Comment: You can run `make` in the background or in another terminal and save the output to a file, then when it's done, read that file into the quickfix

Comment: ... list with `:cfile`. See `:help :cfile`. [First comment timed out.]

Comment: @MIkhail:  check my answer.  I think you are looking for `ex-mode`

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `ex-mode`.  If you type `Q` in normal mode you will get a command prompt style buffer at the bottom of the window.

More information here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Ex-mode